# Differentiating $1/(1-x)$ using the fact that $[x^n]'=nx^{n-1}$?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to differentiate $1/(1-x)$, using the fact that $[x^n]'=nx^{n-1}$ as follows:

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=(1-x)^{-1}$$

Then:

$$[(1-x)^{-1}]'=-1(1-x)^{-2}$$

Here's where I'm confused, what to do with the $-1$? I've done the following:

$$-1(1-x)^{-2}=-1\cdot \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{-1}{(1-x)^2}$$

But it's derivative is actually $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$. I don't know what's wrong in here.

Comment: What you did wrong was to forget to apply the chain rule, as needed (multiply by the derivative of $(1-x)$).

Comment: Do you know the chain rule (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule): $[f(g(x))]^{'}{}={}f^{'}(g(x))g^{'}(x)$? When you calculated $[(1-x)^{-1}]'=-1(1-x)^{-2}$ you should have an extra $-1$ from multiplying by the derivative of $-x$.

Comment: Yes. But somehow, I thought that I could do using only that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Your error is in assuming that differentiating $(1-x)^{-1}$ will be the same as differentiating $x^{-1}$, to be more precise :

$$
[(1-x)^{-1}]'\neq-1(1-x)^{-2}.
$$

Instead use the chain rule :

$$
f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x),
$$

where $f\colon x\mapsto x^{-1}$ and $g\colon x\mapsto 1-x$.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I really thought I could do it using only that fact.

Comment: @Vÿska You can check [this article](http://betterexplained.com/articles/derivatives-product-power-chain/) it will surely clear out things for you.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$\frac{1}{1-x}=(1-x)^{-1}$$ if $x\ne 1$ then we get by the power and chaine rule
$$(-1)(1-x)^{-2}(-1)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember if your derivative is something complex use the formula $n(f(x)^ {(n-1)}). f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)^n$